# Почему мы не пишем в транскрипции?

Tags: орфография, фонетика

Почему, когда мы пишем текст, мы составляем слова из знаков, которые не всегда соответствуют звукам?

Comment: Система «одна буква — один знак» возникла не случайно, и она этому смыслу отвечает. Есть подробности сомнений — от первого лица?

Answer (score 1):

Потому что это было бы неудобно с той точки зрения, что связанные слова эту связь теряли бы. Условно говоря, слова *звон* и *звонарь*, у которых одинаковое начало, потеряли бы это связующее звено: *звон*, но *званарь*.

Более того, звук – понятие неуловимое. Ну вот, скажем, вы произносите слово *не-а*, и там посередине есть гортанная смычка. Это такой особый звук, его нужно было бы обозначать на письме, но это было бы контринтуитивно, ведь этот звук не различает в русском языке ни одну пару слов (сам по себе).

Есть и другие причины.